# Power Query: Check if item in list is a substring of value in a column, return list item if true

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table, let's call it `Markets`, that contains a column of both old and new names. I've also loaded a list `NewMarkets` as a separate query that contains all the new market names.

For example, let's say a value in `Markets[Column 1]` is "Clothing, Textiles, Cloth, Garments". In this case, "Clothing" is the old Market name, and "Textiles, Cloth, Garments" is the new name. I want to be able to search each value in the `Markets` table for the new name, and if none is found, return the existing value in `Markets[Column 1]`.

I tried using the following code as a custom column formula in Markets:

```
let
CurrentValue = [Column 1],
Markets = #"NewMarkets",
MarketFound = List.Select(Markets, each Text.Contains(CurrentValue, _)),
Result = if List.Count(MarketFound) > 0 then MarketFound{0}
else CurrentValue
in 
CurrentValue
```

However, this is just returning the value in Column 1

Here are some samples from Markets[Column 1] and the expected result:

| Column 1 | Expected Value |
| --- | --- |
| Clothing, Textiles, Cloth, Garments | Textiles, Cloth, Garments |
| Steel, Plastics, Manufacturing | Steel, Plastics |
| Offshore, O&G-Refineries | O&G-Refineries |
| Renewables | Renewables |

In this example, the values in the NewMarkets list are [Textiles, Cloth, Garments, Steel, Plastics, O&G-Refineries]

Comment: Please paste your sample data as copiable text along with expected results

Comment: @DavideBacci I added sample data and expected results. For copiable text, column1 is [Clothing, Textiles, Cloth, Garments; Steel, Plastics, Manufacturing; Offshore, O&G-Refineries; Renewables] and Expected Result is [Textiles, Cloth, Garments; Steel, Plastics; O&G-Refineries; Renewables]. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: What you want is unclear. Please provide a better example.  You have two tables, right? Your sample is only showing one table.  What do you want to do? Lookup text from the first table first column against the second table and if there is a match, replace the text in the second table?

Comment: @horseyride Apologies for the confusion. I've added additional sample data and what values I want to be returned; let me know if this helps! For the purposes of this question, the list I mentioned can be considered its own table.

Comment: Did any of these answers help at all? If so, please upvote that answer and then accept it as solution

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. Replaces Column1 in Table1 by checking for words from Column1 Table2, and using Expected Value column of Table2 as the potential replacement

```
//table1 code
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Replacements= Table.Buffer(Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Table2, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source,"Replaced", (x)=> try Table.SelectRows(Replacements, each x[Column1]=[Column1]){0}[Expected Value] otherwise x[Column1] )
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not show an example of your `NewMarkets` table so I hard-coded it as a `List` in the query below. You may want to change that.

In any event, given this **`Markets`** table:
[image]

this code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Markets"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),

//since you did not post it as a table, I hard-coded it as a List"
    #"New Markets" = {"Textiles", "Cloth", "Garments", "Steel", "Plastics", "O&G-Refineries"},

//Replace old with new
    #"Old to New" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Result", (r)=> 
        List.Accumulate(
            List.Transform(Text.Split(r[Column1],","),each Text.Trim(_)),
            null,
            (s, c)=> if List.Contains(#"New Markets", c, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                        then Text.Combine({s, c},", ") else s), type text),
//Replace null Result with Column 1
    #"Replace Null" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Old to New",
        null,
        each if [Result] = null then [Column1] else [Result],
        Replacer.ReplaceValue,
        {"Result"}
    )
        
in
    #"Replace Null"
```

produces produces what you show as an expected ***Result:***
[image]

which seems to be what you show.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Bring both Markets and NewMarkets in Power Query, convert the Markets values into a list and compare this list with the NewMarkets list using List.Intersect

```
let
// Start with old values
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
// Add index column
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

// Convert the values into a list per row
ConvertValuesToList = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "ListsOfOldValues", each  List.Transform( Source[Markets], Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(", ", QuoteStyle.Csv)){[Index]} ),

// Compare these lists just created with the NewMarkets list
#"CompareNew&OldLists" = Table.AddColumn(ConvertValuesToList, "ListofMatchingValues", each List.Intersect( { #"New Markets"[New Markets], [ListsOfOldValues] })),

// Pull out the matching values from this comparison
ExtractNewValues = Table.TransformColumns(#"CompareNew&OldLists", {"ListofMatchingValues", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),

// Remove the intermediate columns which are not needed
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(ExtractNewValues,{"Index", "ListsOfOldValues"})
```

in
#"Removed Columns"